# All projects in Visual Studio 2015 shows MVC missing, ASP.net missing errors, but it shows no error in Visual Studio 17

Tags: model-view-controller, dll, visual-studio-2015, view, intellisense

The project runs without any problem , only intellisense has this problem.

Things I tried

- Cleaned solution
- rebuild solution
- cleared intellisense
- removed and added dll
- copy to local , yes / no toggled
- tried repairing visual studio

[image]

Comment: Hi, if you create a new ASP.NET MVC project in VS 2015, this issue also persists? If so, please go to Control Panel-Programs and Features, right click the VS 2015 and Change-Repair to repair VS 2015, or run the command devenv /safemode or devenv /resetsettings to check if the installed extensions caused this issue, then go to Tools-Extensions and Updates…-Installed to remove one by one to find the culprit or reset the setting to the default one. If this issue only happens in this specific solution, try to delete the hidden folder .vs to restart the VS 2015 and open this solution to test.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT I tried repairing, didn't work. Now reinstalled visual studio and working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by Reinstalling visual Studio.